# No irq handler for vector when using hwinfo --short

Tags: debian, syslog, irq

I have been reading the various fora, while they seem to fix the annoying error, they don't tell the reason why the error crops in the first place.

The error message I get -

```
Message from syslogd@debian at Jul 25 17:33:57 ...
 kernel:[46013.576972] do_IRQ: 2.35 No irq handler for vector

$ sudo dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: PRIME Z270-P
    Version: Rev X.0x
    Serial Number: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Asset Tag: Default string
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Default string
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

The only thing I have left out of this is the motherboard serial number for privacy sake. Can anybody tell me what the core issue might be ?